# Vagrant - VM can not follow host-symlink within virtualbox synced_folder

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, provisioning, vagrantfile

I set up a vagrant machine to maintain an older project of mine. I use VirtualBox as provider and created a synced_folder to publish the project to the vm.

The amount of assets is kind of huge (~40GByte), so i dont want to keep that on my ssd. So i moved those assets to an hdd and created a symlink from my project-folder pointing to the hdd. All of this happens on the host system.

My problem is, that when i ssh into my vagrant machine and inspect the assets-folder i can see a broken symlink. I want my vm to follow this path.

The folder structure (the part, that matters) looks like:

```
root/
|--src/
|--public/
|--|--assets -> /media/hdd
```

As you can see /root/public/assets points to my hdd mount.

My synced_folder is set up like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # skipped lines
    # skipped lines
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"
    # skipped lines
    # skipped lines
end
```

Now i dont know how to configure the synced_folder to follow the path on the host machine.

I thought about having another line like

```
    config.vm.synced_folder "/media/hdd", "/vagrant/public/assets", type: "virtualbox"
```

but i am not the only one using this setup, so i would like to solve it with some kind of option, like:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox", options: ["optionIDontKnowAbout", "1"]
```

What i tried so far:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # should allow symlinks in synced folders
    vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
end
```

But that did not help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the moment i use the following workaround. It does not answer my initial quesion, so i wont delete it:

```
if ENV['USER'].downcase == 'yourusername'
    config.vm.synced_folder "/media/hdd", "/media/hdd", type: "virtualbox"
end
```